# Simulate an inline onkeydown event

Tags: javascript, input, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, keydown

I have an input element which I do not control
for example:

```
<input tabindex="2" onkeypress="if(NotReady_Key())return;fnKeyPressNum(this,'N',0);"onkeydown="if(NotReady_Key())return;fnKeyDownNum(this,9,0);" id="someElement"/>
```

In internet explorer 8 and 9, I am trying to find a way to make the element perform as if the "enter" button has been pressed upon the input,

I failed to find a JS way to simulate the press

but I was thinking, is it possible to grab the inline method:

```
onkeydown="if(NotReady_Key())return;fnKeyDownNum(this,9,0);"
```

from the element, obtain the element by elementById,
and execute it as if the event actually happened?
here is what I tried so far(I am using jquery):

```
 //get dom element
var element = $("#someElement")[0];
//simulate the event
//insert element as "this"
(function(){
fnKeyDownNum(this,9,0);
}).call(element);
```

but it doesn't seem to work as excpected, did I forget something?
I think that I also need to make sure other system variables are simulated other than this, to fully simulate the "ENTER" event.

what can i do?

option 2 is of course to simulate a real key press of "ENTER" right on the input, but i failed to find a way to do so in IE8/9 so far, any way would be accepted even using VBS if thats an option.

please note, I specifically need IE8 and IE9 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to call fnKeyDownNum with an element, give this a try:

```
fnKeyDownNum(document.getElementById('someElement'),9,0);
```

But if you need to really simulate a keypress (because, a keypress can add input to a field, and if you press enter on a form element it also has the effect of submitting the form) you will have to manage that separately.

Comment: Hi james, if you look at the example I provided in my question, I already tried something similar to your suggestion but instead, simulated the whole "this" using the element from the dom (like you did by getElementById). thank you.

Comment: Yep upon closer inspection the code you used will do the same thing - can you elaborate on what it's doing now vs what it should do?  "doesn't work as expected" not clear enough.  Cheers.

Comment: well upon inspection I noticed there is another "system variable" alongside "this" , which is called "event" and the code inside fnKeyDownNum excpects event  var key = event.keyCode;    , so I think I also need to simulate this "event" variable, but I am not sure how to do it via the "call" method.

Comment: Maybe it will work if you trigger a "fake" event.  Give this a try: `$('#someElement').triggerHandler({type: 'keypress', which: 13, keyCode: 13, key: "Enter" });`  You might have to build a similar thing for keydown, depending on what's going on inside those handler functions.